web scraper is not grabbing desired text
I am trying to scrape the sku and description on this site:
https://www.milwaukeetool.com/products/power-tools/drilling/drill-drivers
but, it wont scrape the desired elements despite the code being able to run. Does anyone know why? it looks like I am grabbing the correct elements, I have tried using both requests and selenium (as seen below) and keep getting the same result.
Requests method:
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.milwaukeetool.com/products/power-tools/drilling/drill-drivers'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['sku','desc'])
for item in soup.select("#MTBody > main > section > div.product-listing-main.pt-5.md\:pt-\[30px\] > section:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > a > div.result-title__wrap.absolute.inset-0.top-auto.bg-gray-300.pt-\[5px\].md\:pt-2.px-1.md\:px-4.w-full.text-gray-800.text-center.h-\[75px\]"):
    sku = item.select_one("#MTBody > main > section > div.product-listing-main.pt-5.md\:pt-\[30px\] > section:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > a > div.result-title__wrap.absolute.inset-0.top-auto.bg-gray-300.pt-\[5px\].md\:pt-2.px-1.md\:px-4.w-full.text-gray-800.text-center.h-\[75px\] > span").get_text(strip=True)
    desc = item.select_one("#MTBody > main > section > div.product-listing-main.pt-5.md\:pt-\[30px\] > section:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > a > div.result-title__wrap.absolute.inset-0.top-auto.bg-gray-300.pt-\[5px\].md\:pt-2.px-1.md\:px-4.w-full.text-gray-800.text-center.h-\[75px\] > div.text-brandBlack.font-helvetica67.text-14.result-title.leading-none.max-h-8.overflow-hidden").get_text(strip=True)
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'sku': [sku], 'desc': [desc]})], ignore_index=True)
    print(sku,desc)

df.to_csv("milwaukee.csv",index=False)

Selenium method:
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

options = Options()
driver = uc.Chrome()

website = 'https://www.milwaukeetool.com/products/power-tools/drilling/drill-drivers'
driver.get(website)


product_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".product-listing-main.pt-5.md\\:pt-\\[30px\\]")))
prod_num = []
prod_desc = []

for container in product_list:
    sku = container.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.font-helvetica67.tracking-normal.uppercase.text-gray-900.text-12.result-sku.leading-none').text
    description = container.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.text-brandBlack.font-helvetica67.text-14.result-title.leading-none.max-h-8.overflow-hidden').text
    prod_num.append(sku)
    prod_desc.append(description)


for _ in range(4):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000);")
        time.sleep(2)




driver.quit()
print(len(prod_num))
print(len(prod_desc))
# Create a DataFrame from the scraped data

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'description': prod_desc})

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('milwtest1.csv', index=False)

print(df)


The page is dynamically rendered, so using requests alone is not going to work.
There is an API behind the site but it uses a category ID to retrieve the data. So my approach would have two parts:

use the web page to retrieve the category ID (doesn't contain the actual data because that's retrieved dynamically) and
use the API to retrieve the data.

import re
import requests
from pandas import DataFrame

URL = "https://www.milwaukeetool.com/products/power-tools/drilling/drill-drivers"

# GET CATEGORY ID -------------------------------------------------------------

response = requests.get(URL)

pattern = r'\\\"page_id\\\":\\\"{(\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12})}\\\"'

category_id = re.search(pattern, response.text).groups()[0]

# PULL CATEGORY FROM API ------------------------------------------------------

data = {
    'language': 'en',
    'returnAll': True,
    'categories': category_id,
}

response = requests.post('https://www.milwaukeetool.com/api/v1/products/listing', json=data)


results = response.json()["data"]["results"]

products = []

for result in results:
    products.append({
        "sku": result["sku"],
        "description": result["title"],
    })

products = DataFrame(products)
print(products)

Results look like this:
        sku                                        description
0   2905-20              M18 FUEL™ ½” Drill/Driver w/ ONE-KEY™
1   2903-20                        M18 FUEL™ 1/2" Drill/Driver
2   3403-20                        M12 FUEL™ 1/2" Drill/Driver
3   2505-20    M12 FUEL™ Installation Drill/Driver (Tool-Only)
4   2803-20            M18 FUEL™ 1/2" Drill Driver (Tool Only)
5   2804-20       M18 FUEL™ ½” Hammer Drill/Driver (Tool Only)
6   2503-20            M12 FUEL™ 1/2" Drill Driver (Tool Only)
7   2810-20   M18 FUEL™ Mud Mixer with 180° Handle (Tool Only)
8   3602-20    M18™ Compact Brushless 1/2" Hammer Drill/Driver
9   3601-20          M18™ Compact Brushless 1/2" Drill/ Driver
10  2902-20        M18 1/2" Brushless Hammer Drill (Tool Only)
11  2801-20  M18 Compact Brushless 1/2" Drill Driver Bare Tool
12  2407-20                 M12™ 3/8” Drill/Driver (Tool Only)
13  2606-20                             M18™ 1/2" Drill Driver
14  2615-20                             M18™ Right Angle Drill
15  0726-20        M28™ Cordless 1/2" Hammer Drill (Tool Only)
16   1107-6                       1/2 D-Handle Drill 0-500 RPM
17   1610-1                         1/2" Compact Drill 650 RPM
18   0244-1                     1/2"  Magnum® Drill, 0-700 RPM
19  0101-20  1/4" Magnum® Drill, 0-4000 RPM with QUIK-LOK® ...
20  0302-20  1/2"  Magnum® Drill, 0-850 RPM with All Metal ...
21  0233-20  3/8" Magnum® Drill, 0-2800 RPM with Keyless Chuck
22   0234-6                     1/2"  Magnum® Drill, 0-950 RPM
23   1660-6                         1/2" Compact Drill 450 RPM
24  0100-20  1/4" Magnum® Drill, 0-2500 RPM with QUIK-LOK® ...
25   1101-1                         1/2 D-Handle Drill 500 RPM
26  0200-20                     3/8" Magnum® Drill, 0-1200 RPM
27  0240-20                                         3/8" Drill
28   1630-1                        1/2"  Compact Drill 900 RPM
29   1007-1                       1/2 D-Handle Drill 0-600 RPM
30  0370-20                    3/8"  Close Quarter Angle Drill
31  0299-20                    1/2"  Magnum®  Drill, 0-850 RPM
32  0201-20  3/8" Magnum® Drill, 0-2500 RPM with All Metal ...
33   1001-1                   1/2 in. D-Handle Drill 0-600 RPM
34  0202-20  3/8" Magnum®  Drill, 0-1200 RPM with All Metal...
35  0235-21  1/2"  Magnum®  Drill, 0-950 RPM with All Metal...
36  0300-20                      1/2" Magnum® Drill, 0-850 RPM


Pls refer to the loc(CSS selector or XPath) in following template:
  <actions>
    <action_goto url="https://www.milwaukeetool.com/products/power-tools/drilling/drill-drivers" />
    <action_loopineles>
      <element loc="div.product-listing__results-list > div > div a" />
      <action_extract tabname="dat_00000000000012ab">
        <column_element colname="c01" nickname="sku">
          <element loc="span.font-helvetica67" />
          <!-- <element loc=".//span[contains(@class, 'font-helvetica67')]" /> -->
          <transform>
            <fun_replace substr="(" newstr="" />
            <fun_replace substr=")" newstr="" />
          </transform>
        </column_element>
        <column_element colname="c02" nickname="description">
          <element loc="div.result-title__wrap > div.text-brandBlack" />
        </column_element>
      </action_extract>
    </action_loopineles>
  </actions>

Extracted data:

Or you can extract the data from the response of resquest:

